# Hibernate Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)

Tags: hibernate, thymeleaf, enumerated

How I can save Enum's String value (password) to database? Now I can save only Enum type (`ID_CARD`, `INTERNATIONAL_PASSPORT`).

My Enum Class

```
public enum Citizen {

    ID_CARD("Id card"),
    INTERNATIONAL_PASSPORT("International passport"),
    FOREIGN_PASSPORT("Foreign passport");

    private String passport;

    private Citizen(String passport){
        this.passport = passport;
    }

    public String getPassport(){
        return passport;
    }
}
```

​

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "citizen")
public class Client implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "inn")
    private long inn;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "citizen")
    private Citizen citizen;
}
```

HTML page:

```
<select th:field="${client.citizen}">
    <!--/*@thymesVar id="state" type=""*/-->
    <option th:each="state :   ${T(models.client.Citizen).getCitizens()}"
            th:value="${state}" th:text="${state}">
    </option>
</select>
```

I wanna save like th:value="${state.passport}"
                            th:text="${state.passport}"

Comment: Why do you want to save enum property? Enums are constants.

Comment: I want to save String value in brackets  -> ID_CARD("Id card")